# How to concatenate two files and write between them?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am trying to achieve something like this with bash script:

c.txt:

```
contents of a.txt
###
contents of b.txt
```

Basically I want to write a constant string between the contents of two files and save to a new one without modifying the originals.

This was the closest I could get:

```
echo "###" >> a.txt|cat b.txt >> out.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `-` as a filename usually means to use standard input. Thus:

```
echo 'something' | cat a.txt - b.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with three commands:

```
cat a.txt > out.txt
echo "###" >> out.txt
cat b.txt >> out.txt
```

And perhaps make a function out of it:

```
append_hash() { cat $1 > $3; echo "###" >> $3; cat $2 >> $3; }
```

Usage:

```
append_hash a.txt b.txt out.txt
```

Comment: You can also combine these into one: `{ cat a.txt; echo "###"; cat b.txt; } > out.txt`. This is more efficient (although not significantly so), since it only has to open `out.txt` once, instead of once per command.